# Why can't I select a DataTables row using Bootstrap events?

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-5, flask-wtforms

I followed [Miguels’s tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/beautiful-interactive-tables-for-your-flask-templates) successfully for rendering a table with data in on of my Flask templates.

I have problems with the next step: selecting one of the rows in the table.
The event in question is `click-row.bs.table` (according to https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/api/events/).

I can't get this to work in my code.

```
<script>
  $('#stekTable').on('click-cell.bs.table', function (field, value, row) {
    alert ('succes');
  })
</script>
```

What does work is the click event

```
<script>
  $('#stekTable').on('click', function () {
    alert ('succes');
  })
</script>
```

I suspect it has to do with the new version of Bootstrap (version 5), but I'm not sure => Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery.

According to the documentation it is still possible to use jQuery, but I can't get it to work.

(https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/javascript/).

> Still want to use jQuery? It’s possible!
> Bootstrap 5 is designed to be used without jQuery, but it’s still possible to use our components with jQuery. If Bootstrap detects jQuery in the window object it’ll add all of our components in jQuery’s plugin system; this means you’ll be able to do $('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip() to enable tooltips. The same goes for our other components.

I almost threw my laptop out the window. So it's time to ask for help.

---

Demo added by community:

```js
$('#stekTable').on('click-cell.bs.table', function(field, value, row) {
  console.log('success');
});
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table id="stekTable" data-toggle="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Item ID</th>
        <th>Item Name</th>
        <th>Item Price</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
        <td>$1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
        <td>$2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-table@1.19.1/dist/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hard to tell if your issue is with the bootstrap version, the datatables.js for bootstrap or something else here.

Comment: I've added a demo above. Does it represent your case? It seems to work fine.

Comment: I got my code working using the demo.
The difference is made by [a] the unpkg-cdn-files (css and js) and [b] the data toggle attribute (was new to me).
I don't quite understand why it works now.
I think it mainly has to do with the content of the cdn files (I find it rather non-transparent, but maybe it's just me).
I will continue to work on it in the coming period and trust that I will get a better grip on it.
For now I am happy - thanks for the help.